# unexpected end-of-file found in ANSI-C Header

Tags: c

I am currently trying to follow the free book you can find [here](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ats/books/ooc.pdf)

It tries to make C object oriented and I found it to be intriguing so I wanted to give it a try. I am new with C but have used other languages like C# and Java. The problem though, is that the code doesn't compile. I am using VS2013 Premiere and I set the flags for the project to be ANSI and C. It gives me the error "Unexpected end-of-file found" in the "new.h" file.

Code looks like this:

```
#ifndef NEW_H
#define NEW_H

void * new (const void * type);
void delete (void * item);

#endif
```

What am I missing about this code?

Comment: 1) Try to add a newline in the end. 2) Try to rename the functions, such that the y are not the same as C++ keywords

Comment: Also make sure the precompiled header setting is set to "off".

Comment: I added the new line, and it still says unexpected end of file. I generated an empty project which removes precompiled headers.

Comment: Rename all identifiers called `new` to `mynew`. VS2013 is a c++ compiler and in c++ `new` is a keyword.

Comment: No, I figured it out. It turns out that @EugeneSh. was right. I didn't read the errors probably and it had moved from "new.h" to "object.h" after I added the new line. So I added a new line to all the headers and it fixed the header errors. Now I just have 8 other errors in main xD

Comment: @MichaelWalz No, the MS compiler also has a C mode. The given code compiles fine for me with the MS compiler when included from a `.c` file.